How to I fix this recessed medicine cabinet framing?
What is behind my walls looks nothing like the lovely Home Depot DIY video of installing a recessed medicine cabinet!
Why is there so much extra wood in here? What is that weird little plank behind the old mirror with massive nails pounded into...the drywall on the other side? Why is there another vertical piece of wood above the mirror framing? Why does the light fixture need a metal clamp with a long leg?

My new medicine cabinet is a few inches wider and higher than the old one. The opening is cut for the recess size needed for the new cabinet.
How do I: 1) get the old framing out of there? 2) get framing for the new mirror in there?
The vertical planks go from floor to ceiling. God knows what that flat middle piece is connected to and I can only see one nail holding the upper horizontal plank in place and can't access the nails holding the lower one in place.
Basically, I feel like I'm gonna need to cut a lot more drywall out to have room to work...especially above the mirror to prep for new bath lighting.
I'm pretty handy with drywall, tiles, and light electrical but this is my first time having to deal with wood framing. I really thought I was just gonna have my neighbor cut me a couple of 2x4s and drill everything into place but here we are!

More drywall cutting will allow you see to what everything is.  The 2x4 above the blocking is probably just there for the light box to be mounted.  The thin plank is unknown, but maybe just a nailing/screwing plate for drywall repair on the other side.

The studs are probably structural, so now is when you need to decide on a surface-mount versus a recessed cabinet. If you need recessed, you’re pulling off drywall from the floor up to at least the light, a little wider than the cab. (And the metal leg below the junction box is holding the jbox securely. Alternatives exist.)

Oh, and if there’s a base cabinet down below, that’s coming off temporarily. And you might discover plumbing in the way.

Ok. Cut a little further above the opening. There is a narrow wood plank (barely visible at the top of this photo) in the center of the cut that the flat middle piece of wood is nailed to.
@aloysius Recessed is the only option as this is an old house and the bath is super tiny. Cutting the wall to the floor isn't an option because just below this is the original tile wall. (No plans to remove it.) The stud on the left might be load bearing but the one on the right is just about 3 inches from the corner of the room where another floor to ceiling stud is located..

@AloysiusDefenestrate what makes you so sure this is structural framing?  It's clearly an interior wall.

@Huesmann — Interior walls are still structural. (I didn’t say ‘load bearing’, which is a different thing.) Point is, you can’t just hack out the studs blindly. Now, knowing that the right hand stud is close to the corner makes a bit of a difference. One might get away with a simpler sill/header with less drywall damage, but dancing near the edge is above my paygrade.

Additional thought: get a smaller medicine cabinet.

Thank you for the sounding board internet friends. Since I've already got to get a new electrical box for the replacement light, I decided to return the absolutely lovely medicine cabinet I bought in exchange for a narrower (though taller) one so I only have to cut out one stud out of the wall.
Final thought: I'm still very open to suggestions on how to get that center piece of wood out without completely destroying the surrounding drywall which is what I anticipate my reciprocal saw doing. My oscilator is on its last leg. :(

Oscillating tools are always useful. If mine died, I’d replace it immediately. If you plunge buzz a notch with the grain, close to the edge of the wide board, you can probably lever it and split it with a big slot screwdriver. Keep working your way across the board like that, aiming to split at the existing screws.

Just wanted to close this out… Ended up getting a smaller medicine cabinet that could fit between the two studs. Cut the wall all the way up to the ceiling to see what was going on behind there and move the light box up about 6 inches. Did use the reciprocating saw to cut through the nails holding the horizontal plank. Punctured the drywall about 5 times in total(!!) Have quite a bit of patching to do but ultimately, the bathroom is getting the desired upgrade!
